# Migrate from Perforce to Subversion

Tags: svn, perforce

I have started work for a company which is in the process of in-housing their main application previously managed by an agency.

The codebase is currently stored in a Perforce repository. What I would like to do is migrate this codebase, complete with revision history, to a newly built Subvesrion server.

Is anyone aware of any scripts or tools that will help me acomplish this?

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: are you really certain that porting to SVN would be better than implementing Perforce in the company you are working for? Yes, Perforce costs money, but there are benefits too, particularly in the area of support for merging changes between branches.

Comment: It's a fair comment. My first action was to build a new Subversion server and migrate a very large and old codebase (seperate to the one they are in-housing) they had on an ancient Subversion box to this new one. Now that I have a shiny new Subversion server, I'd like to use it, as well as only require developers to use one source-control solution.

I suppose I could have built a new Perforce box instead, migrated their code to Perforce and imported the code from the application they are in-housing, but I decided to stay with what they were already using.

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://p42svn.tigris.org/

But I agree with the earlier comments - I've gone the other direction, moving projects from SVN to Perforce because SVN could not cut it when it came to merging.  Maybe it's gotten much better since 1.5.4, but while P4 has it's oddities and complexities - it's a more robust solution for large projects that do branching.